# Is there a way for a logo image to have a greater height than the navigation bar and still be fully visible?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a situation where I need to create something like this:
[image: Logo image]

The problem is that the logo is higher than the navigation bar is, and I want this all to be a part of the navigation bar. I’ve tried “pushing” the logo from the top, but it doesn’t really work. If I increase the height of the logo image, it just cuts it off where the navigation bar ends.
Also, the back button should be aligned to the top of the logo image.

Currently I am using a custom view for this and hiding the navigation bar, which I hate, so if anyone has any advice/suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting title view's clip to bounds and masks to bounds to false by setting

```
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.clipsToBounds = false
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.layer.masksToBounds = false
```